# Aforge image processing using nokia qt

Tags: image, qt, image-processing, aforge

Just a quick question: is it possible to use the image porcessing uitilities used in AForge using Nokia Qt? I have tried searching on the internet for similar work done by others but I have yet to come accross any matches. I know AForge is written using C# so it is directly used in Visual Studio.

I ask becasue I am developing an image extraction tool; i have extracted the raw image data and wish to grayscale the image to then run it through a Canny Edge detector. I also wish to have the option to first use binarization then run the image through Canny (after graysacaling). The reason why I wish to use the Aforge tools is because I am conducting an investigation to compare these methods to Sobel Edge Detection; the images that I am extracting were also processed using the AForge tools so I wish to use the same tools to keep the processing as consistant as possible.

Actually, if you guys/gals have any recommendations on what to use in terms of processing tools I would welcome them for consideration.

:)